# Best methods to integrate summed probability and uncertainty from multiple sources?

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, threshold, numerical-integration

I am trying to calculate risk of coastal flooding. In our model, we have 4 major sources of uncertainty:

- Elevation at location (height + gaussian error)
- Sea level rise (value at any given year + gaussian uncertainty)
- Max high tide (GEV distribution, parameter uncertainty)
- Waves (lognormal distribution, parameter uncertainty)

I need to calculate the probability of `elevation < SLR + tide + wave`, ideally with some estimate of total uncertainty for each year.

I guess the best way to calculate the probability is using 4-dimensional numerical integration (like scipy's `nquad`), with a function that sets the joint PDF to zero when it's below the height threshold. However, I think this is fairly computationally complex in 4D, and I'm wondering if there might be a more sensible way to do it, or even an analytical solution?

Secondly, for the uncertainty estimate, is there any way to calculate this directly (does the height threshold even impact the answer?), or is the only reasonable way to do it via a markov chain analysis?

Comment: 1) Are your random variables independent? If not, do you have a joint distribution? 2) What does parameter uncertainty mean? Do you have a distribution over parameter values? 3) Do you want to evaluate this at multiple locations? If so, which components depend on location, and which are invariant?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure they're independent. tide is an annual maximum, wave is just the distribution of all waves. Yes, if I use MLE to estimate the distribution parameter, then those have uncertainty associated with them. I want to evaluate it independently at every location. None of the values are spatially invariant.